# Select several most recent emails as one row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

In my project I have a table of user emails EMAILS:

```
|     ID |      PROFILE_ID |        EMAIL | LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP|
___________________________________________________________________
|       1|                1|       a@a.com|    2017-02-02 15:13:46|
|       2|                1|       b@b.com|    2017-02-01 15:13:46|
|       3|                2|       c@c.com|    2017-02-03 15:13:46|
```

where PROFILE_ID refers to the user profiles table PROFILES. I'd like to get 2(N in general) most recent distinct emails for each user profile as a one row:

```
|     PROFILE_ID |      EMAIL_1    |      EMAIL_2 |
__________________________________________________
|               1|          b@b.com|       a@a.com|
|               2|          c@c.com|          NULL|
```

I tried many queries, the last one I stopped on is below:

```
SELECT
  EMAIL1.PROFILE_ID,
  EMAIL1.EMAIL AS EMAIL_1,
  EMAIL2.EMAIL AS EMAIL_2
FROM EMAILS EMAIL1
  LEFT JOIN
  EMAILS EMAIL2
    ON EMAIL1.PROFILE_ID = EMAIL2.PROFILE_ID AND EMAIL2.LAST_UPD_TMST <= EMAIL1.LAST_UPD_TMST AND EMAIL1.ID <> EMAIL2.ID
```

but it gives me extra records for profile containing several emails:

```
|     PROFILE_ID |      EMAIL_1    |      EMAIL_2 |
__________________________________________________
|               1|          b@b.com|       a@a.com|
|               1|          a@a.com|          NULL|
|               2|          c@c.com|          NULL|
```

I use Oracle 11g but keep in mind MySql compatibility if possible. Could anyone say what is wrong in the query mentioned above?

Comment: Is 2 the maximum number of emails per profile_id?

Comment: "In general, N" will not work, because in Oracle the number of columns in the output must be known at parse time, long before the data is inspected - and N is dependent on the data in the table. Why do you want to do this in SQL and not in your reporting application?

Comment: @JohnHC, no, there may be more than two emails per profile.

Comment: @mathguy, because of performance reasons. In fact, there is another table with phones and I'd like to get 4 distinct records from there, that's why I said "N". There is no need to set N as query parameter.

Comment: What is wrong in your query is easy to spot: the row with `a@a.com` does not have a match in the join, but you are doing an outer join; that row is in the same position as the row for PROFILE_ID = 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select profile_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then email end) as email1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then email end) as email2
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by profile_id order by last_updated_timestamp) as seqnum
      from emails e
     ) e
group by profile_id;
```

If you really do want to remove duplicates, then you can aggregate the data before the `row_number()`.  To get the *last* occurrence of duplicate emails:

```
select profile_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then email end) as email1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then email end) as email2
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by profile_id order by last_updated_timestamp) as seqnum
      from (select profile_id, email, max(last_updated_timestamp) as last_updated_timestamp
            from emails e
            group by profile_id, email
           ) e
     ) e
group by profile_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, looks like you missed right parenthesis in the query: select profile_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then email end) as email1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then email end) as email2
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by profile_id order by last_updated_timestamp) **AS seqnum**
      from emails e
     ) e
group by profile_id;

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle 11 you can use the PIVOT operator. I don't know MySQL, but I believe it doesn't have a PIVOT operator.

```
with
     test_data ( ID, PROFILE_ID, EMAIL, LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP ) as (
       select 1, 1, 'a@a.com', to_timestamp('2017-02-02 15:13:46', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
       from dual union all
       select 2, 1, 'b@b.com', to_timestamp('2017-02-01 15:13:46', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
       from dual union all
       select 3, 2, 'c@c.com', to_timestamp('2017-02-03 15:13:46', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
       from dual
     )
--  end of test data (not part of the solution); SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE
select profile_id, email_1, email_2
from   ( select profile_id, email, 
                row_number() over (partition by profile_id 
                                   order by last_updated_timestamp desc) as rn
         from   test_data
       )
pivot (min(email) for rn in (1 as email_1, 2 as email_2))
;

PROFILE_ID EMAIL_1 EMAIL_2
---------- ------- -------
         1 a@a.com b@b.com
         2 c@c.com

2 rows selected.
```

Comment: thank you for the solution! The only comment is, this query must be combined wit the second query of @GordonLinoff in order to avoid duplicates and get only unique values.